# Criar dropdown usando lista em angular

Tags: angular, dropdown

Eu tenho um dropdown no header, porém preciso passar as opções pra uma lista, porque assim fica muito difícil de manipular. Esse é o código que eu tenho:

```html
<button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu3" class="menuItems p-button-text">
  <span>Botão header</span>
</button>

<mat-menu #menu3="matMenu">
  <button mat-menu-item routerLink="/foo" class="menuItems p-button-text">
    <span>Option 1</span>
  </button>
  <button mat-menu-item routerLink="/foo" class="menuItems p-button-text">
    <span>Option 2</span>
  </button>
  <button mat-menu-item routerLink="/foo" class="menuItems p-button-text">
    <span>Option 3</span>
  </button>
  <button mat-menu-item routerLink="/foo" class="menuItems p-button-text">
    <span>Option 4</span>
  </button>
</mat-menu>
```

Ele funciona, mas preciso dessas opções sendo passada como uma lista.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para isto vc vai usar o `*ngFor`. Primeiro vc cria um array no seu componente:

```
readonly items = [
  { link: "/foo/1", text: "Option 1" },
  { link: "/foo/2", text: "Option 2" },
  { link: "/foo/3", text: "Option 3" },
  { link: "/foo/4", text: "Option 4" },
];
```

E usa no template da seguinte forma:

```html
<button
  *ngFor="let item of items"
  mat-menu-item
  [routerLink]="item.link"
  class="menuItems p-button-text"
>
  <span>{{ item.text }}</span>
</button>
```

Olha o código completo:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  template: `
    <button
      mat-button
      [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu3"
      class="menuItems p-button-text"
    >
      <span>Botão header</span>
    </button>

    <mat-menu #menu3="matMenu">
      <button
        *ngFor="let item of items"
        mat-menu-item
        [routerLink]="item.link"
        class="menuItems p-button-text"
      >
        <span>{{ item.text }}</span>
      </button>
    </mat-menu>
  `,
})
export class AppComponent {
  readonly items = [
    { link: "/foo/1", text: "Option 1" },
    { link: "/foo/2", text: "Option 2" },
    { link: "/foo/3", text: "Option 3" },
    { link: "/foo/4", text: "Option 4" },
  ];
}
```